# How to return True/False if dictionary is found in Pandas Datraframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is pretty straight forward, I just can't seem to find an easy answer (It seems like this should be very easy).

Does python have a built in function that will check to see if a dictionary is found in the dataframe, returning either true or false.

sample dataframe

```
>>> df  = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[546,107,478,546,478], 'ID2':['AUSER','BUSER','CUSER','AUSER','EUSER'], 'DO':[3,6,8,4,6], 'DATA':['ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG','ORIG']})
>>> df
   DATA  DO   ID    ID2
0  ORIG   3  546  AUSER
1  ORIG   6  107  BUSER
2  ORIG   8  478  CUSER
3  ORIG   4  546  AUSER
4  ORIG   6  478  EUSER

>>> true_sample  = {'DO': 3, 'ID2': 'AUSER'}
>>> false_sample = {'DO': 6, 'ID2': 'AUSER'}
```

I'v been trying to make df.isin() work, but I't seems to expect the dict values to be a list. Can anyone offer an easy check?

**EDIT:** 
I already see some great ideas pouring in, but to be clear, the desire is to use the logic to evaluate from an if clause. This is a throw away example, (i'm not actually defining a function, I'm just using f() to represent the logic that will be used);

```
>>> if f(true_sample):
>>>    print("yeah it's there")
>>> if not f(false_sample):
>>>    print("Doesn't exist in the dataframe")
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the dataframe has an entry `true_sample` or do you want to check if there is an entry in your dataframe with `'DO' = 6` and check the corresponding `'ID2'`?

Comment: @Dorian, if I understand you correctly, it would be the latter. the desired output of the function evaluating true_sample would be True and of false_sample would be False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert those true_sample and false_samples into dataframes and use merge to get only the True or False samples from df like this:

```
df_true = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(true_sample, orient='index').T.merge(df, on=['DO','ID2'])
```

Output:

```
  DO    ID2   ID  DATA
0  3  AUSER  546  ORIG
```

Comment: i found that using the following actually works much better, than the original answer I accepted. Thank you! `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(true_sample, orient='index').T.merge(df).empty`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)  and [`numpy.ndarray.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) with a list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.logical_and(*[df[k].eq(v) for k, v in true_sample.items()])
mask.any()
```

[out]

```
True
```

---

You can also use this mask to index your `DataFrame` if needed:

```
df[mask]
```

[out]

```
    ID    ID2  DO  DATA
0  546  AUSER   3  ORIG
```

---

#### Example of usage as a `def`:

```
def contains_dict(df, d):
    mask = np.logical_and(*[df[k].eq(v) for k, v in d.items()])
    if mask.any():
        print("yeah it's there")
    else:
        print("Doesn't exist in the dataframe")

contains_dict(df, true_sample)
```

[out]

```
yeah it's there
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed (whether or not I actually define the function). As bonus points (if I ever need it in the future), could you make this function work even with an unknown number of items in the dict? So it would correctly work with the existing examples plus: `true_sample2  = {'DO': 3, 'ID2': 'AUSER', 'ID':546 }` & `true_sample3  = {'DO': 3, 'ID2': 'AUSER', 'ID':546, 'DATA':'ORIG'}`

Answer (score 1):

First `update` your `dict` , then we create another `DataFrame` , `merge`

```
true_sample.update({'Key':'True'});false_sample.update({'Key':'Fasle'})
yourdf=df.merge(pd.DataFrame([true_sample,false_sample]),how='left')
# notice here I would like keep the key instead drop the row.
Out[199]: 
    ID    ID2  DO  DATA   Key
0  546  AUSER   3  ORIG  True
1  107  BUSER   6  ORIG   NaN
2  478  CUSER   8  ORIG   NaN
3  546  AUSER   4  ORIG   NaN
4  478  EUSER   6  ORIG   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if `true_sample` is in the dataframe, you can use the `.any()` method.

```
>>> ((df['DO'] == 3) & (df['ID2'] == AUSER)).any()
True
>>> ((df['DO'] == 6) & (df['ID2'] == AUSER)).any()
False
```